# SQL ranking using Set Theory not Cursors

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have managed to consolidate data from different sources, with a view to producing a film ranking from viewings around the world. In a dream situation my data would be so complete that creating a ranking would be easy, but I can only go on what I have. When I look at the data, I know by eyeballing how to get the computer to do how my eyes are ranking the films, but that is in a cursor way, which will take some doing coding anyway. Ideally I would like to use SQL how it is supposed to be used, Set theory. Does anyone have an idea as to how I could do this?

The eyeballing method, based on table being ordered by country.

I see that in Australia (sydney) 4 films have been rated, so that's my starting point, where the Best Film is Scent Of A Woman, then Expendables, then the good bad ugly,  and then die hard. Then I look a Belgium, and see that neither Good Will Hunting nor Kill Bill has been rated in Australia, so I put those to one side for a moment, and go on to France and Paris. here I see that The Good Bad Ugly is rated as 1st, and 3rd in Australia, so I know that First Contact and Good will hunting is rated at the same level as Die hard.... until I can see from other countries if Die hard has been compared to Good will Hunting and Expendables.... and so on.......

O, The fields Ranking is the rank, and Total Ranking is the number of films ranked for a country by a city....

[image]

It's a tricky one, and has been on my mind for a few days now....

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[QuestionToAsk2]
(
    [ranking] [bigint] NULL,
    [totalrank] [bigint] NULL,
    [Film] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Country] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [City] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT [dbo].[QuestionToAsk2] ([ranking], [totalrank], [Film], [Country], 
[City]) 
VALUES (1, 2, N'***First Contact', N'***UK', N'Manchester'),
       (2, 2, N'***Dumb And Dumber', N'***UK', N'Manchester'),
       (1, 3, N'***Shawshank Redemption', N'***Germany', N'Munich'),
       (2, 3, N'***The Expendibles', N'***Germany', N'Munich'),
       (3, 3, N'***The Notebook', N'***Germany', N'Munich'),
       (1, 2, N'***Kill Bill', N'***Germany', N'Hamburg'),
       (2, 2, N'***King Arthur', N'***Germany', N'Hamburg'),
       (1, 2, N'***Good Will Hunting', N'***Belgium', N'Brussels'),
       (2, 2, N'***Kill Bill', N'***Belgium', N'Brussels'),
       (1, 5, N'***First Contact', N'***Russia', N'Moscow'),
       (2, 5, N'***Good Will Hunting', N'***Russia', N'Moscow'),
       (3, 5, N'***Scent Of A Woman', N'***Russia', N'Moscow'),
       (4, 5, N'***Sea Of Love', N'***Russia', N'Moscow'),
       (1, 3, N'***The Godfather part 3', N'***Japan', N'Tokyo'),
       (2, 3, N'***Scent Of A Woman', N'***Japan', N'Tokyo'),
       (3, 3, N'***Sea Of Love', N'***Japan', N'Tokyo'),
       (1, 2, N'***Star Wars Episode IV', N'***Portugal', N'Porto'),
       (2, 2, N'***First Contact', N'***Portugal', N'Porto'),
       (1, 2, N'***Star Wars Episode IV', N'***USA', N'Boston'),
       (2, 2, N'***Revenge Of The Sith', N'***USA', N'Boston'),
       (1, 2, N'***Good Will Hunting', N'***Italy', N'Rome'),
       (2, 2, N'***Sea Of Love', N'***Italy', N'Rome'),
       (1, 4, N'***Scent Of A Woman', N'***Australia', N'Sydney'),
       (2, 4, N'***The Expendibles', N'***Australia', N'Sydney'),
       (3, 4, N'***The Good The Bad and The Ugly', N'***Australia', N'Sydney'),
       (4, 4, N'***Die Hard', N'***Australia', N'Sydney'),
       (1, 2, N'***Kill Bill', N'***Switzerland', N'Geneva'),
       (2, 2, N'***King Arthur', N'***Switzerland', N'Geneva'),
       (1, 4, N'***Scent Of A Woman', N'***UK', N'London'),
       (2, 4, N'***Shawshank Redemption', N'***UK', N'London'),
       (3, 4, N'***Die Hard', N'***UK', N'London'),
       (4, 4, N'***The Notebook', N'***UK', N'London'),
       (1, 3, N'***The Good The Bad and The Ugly', N'***France', N'Paris'),
       (2, 3, N'***First Contact', N'***France', N'Paris'),
       (3, 3, N'***Good Will Hunting', N'***France', N'Paris'),
       (1, 3, N'***First Contact', N'***Spain', N'Madrid'),
       (2, 3, N'***Good Will Hunting', N'***Spain', N'Madrid'),
       (3, 3, N'***The Good The Bad and The Ugly', N'***Spain', N'Madrid'),
       (1, 2, N'***Shawshank Redemption', N'***Poland', N'Warsaw'),
       (2, 2, N'***Good Will Hunting', N'***Poland', N'Warsaw'),
       (1, 2, N'***Scent Of A Woman', N'***Slovakia', N'Poprad'),
       (2, 2, N'***Shawshank Redemption', N'***Slovakia', N'Poprad'),
       (1, 3, N'***The Notebook', N'***Slovakia', N'Kosice'),
       (2, 3, N'***Sea Of Love', N'***Slovakia', N'Kosice'),
       (3, 3, N'***Shawshank Redemption', N'***Slovakia', N'Kosice'),
       (1, 3, N'***First Contact', N'***France', N'Cannes'),
       (2, 3, N'***Dumb And Dumber', N'***France', N'Cannes'),
       (3, 3, N'***Shawshank Redemption', N'***France', N'Cannes'),
       (1, 3, N'***Scent Of A Woman', N'***USA', N'New York'),
       (2, 3, N'***Star Wars Episode IV', N'***USA', N'New York'),
       (3, 3, N'***Revenge Of The Sith', N'***USA', N'New York'),
       (1, 2, N'***Star Wars Episode IV', N'***Slovakia', N'Bratislava'),
       (2, 2, N'***The Notebook', N'***Slovakia', N'Bratislava'),
       (1, 2, N'***Scent Of A Woman', N'***Portugal', N'Lisbon'),
       (2, 2, N'***Die Hard', N'***Portugal', N'Lisbon');
```

Comment: What is your question here? You forgot to ask one.

Comment: My question is how do I use SQL using set theory, and not get it to rank the films in the way a human would by eyeballing, in a cursorial way. It may be that I HAVE to use the cursor approach, but Set theory is quicker and less prone to errors of logic in coding. ..... (thanks for editing the code btw)

Comment: I haven't coded the cursorial approach as yet as it's gonna be a minefield to code, especially as the data is dynamic not static, and could have so many tiers, so can't hard code values, but if someone has a set theory approach to solving then that would be incredible.

Comment: It might help if you add expected results to your question.

Comment: It seems that you have hard-coded the results, which is not helpful as we don't know the structure and sample of the source data that will produce this result.

Comment: How do you want to handle ties?

Comment: Good responses to a tricky problem. Dan Guzman, to produce an expected result I'll need to process manually, as I don't have a coded solution (cursor logic other otherwise) , it will probably involve pivoting the countries and cities against the film rated, although i try to avoid pivot with SQL as SQL needs to know (hard coded) what the Countries and cities are before, ie it's not dynamic. Wolfgang, yes it is a sample, it would be impossible to provide anything else here. Habo, if there were exact ties they should have the same ranking, it wouldn't matter if it was Rank or Dense Rank.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, it's given me some ideas, that may help me to either solve, or come back with more definitive questions.

Comment: Isn't it simply `COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY Country, City)`?

Comment: Alas no HoneyBadger as that equates to TotalRank which is the field showing the total number of films rated by a country by a city. I stumbled across some lovely code on this forum for dynamic pivoting, and am using that to visualise where to go from here, and will comment again if that proves useful. Thanks for your continued interest on a -1 rated post :)

Comment: @user9930055, a rating of -1 means very little, sadly. I'm still struggling to understand the logic behind your requested ranking though...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, this should do it.  I have recreated some of your data but added a fictional Film Rating column so we actually have something to rank on.

```
CREATE TABLE #QuestionToAsk2
(
    [Film] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Country] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [City] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [FilmRating] int
) 
GO

INSERT into #QuestionToAsk2 ([Film], [Country], [City], [FilmRating]) 
VALUES (N'***First Contact', N'***UK', N'Manchester', 9),
       (N'***Dumb And Dumber', N'***UK', N'Manchester', 10),
       (N'***Shawshank Redemption', N'***Germany', N'Munich', 7),
       (N'***The Expendibles', N'***Germany', N'Munich', 4),
       (N'***The Notebook', N'***Germany', N'Munich', 2),
       (N'***Kill Bill', N'***Germany', N'Hamburg', 6),
       (N'***King Arthur', N'***Germany', N'Hamburg', 5),
       (N'***Good Will Hunting', N'***Belgium', N'Brussels', 3),
       (N'***Kill Bill', N'***Belgium', N'Brussels', 5)


select 
 rank() over(partition by city order by [FilmRating] desc) [Rank]
,count(*) over(partition by City) [TotalRank]
,film
,Country
,City
,[FilmRating]
from #QuestionToAsk2 a
```

This produces:

[image: Output]

Comment: Hi GandRalph, alas your added column doesn't represent real votes. My situation is similar to the analogy of a marathon race. Let's say a guy called Edwards comes 5th in the London marathon, & beats someone called Smith who comes 8th. Let's say I want to know if Edwards is better than a guy called Johnson, but they have never raced in the same race, but Johnson & Smith have, & Smith beat him. I could then predict that Edwards would beat Johnson based on the above....

Comment: I am trying to compare films based on the sample data provided, that have never been specifically compared to each other, similar to my marathon race analogy. I can't just compare the actual total of votes for each film, as the sample size of the votes across each system is totally different, much like saying i can't just compare the finish times of all the marathons and just order on that, as the conditions were totally different, eg it was pissing it down in the London marathon, and so on average the london runners were slower than other marathons....

Comment: Then your question is not directly an SQL question.  SQL requires hard data, you can then query this hard data to get the exact result.  You are asking for an overall methodology on how to accomplish something based on data you haven't specified.  Please provide an example data set (preferably with the create table code for us to make it easy) and the exact expected output.  Please also include the exact code you have tried so far.  We can then assist with providing alternative code to achieve your desired output.

Comment: Unfortunately the world and the predictions we ask computers to make are often based on incomplete data. The information I provided as an example is masking sensitive data, (replaced by film names, countries, and cities). It's far from as straight forward as a simple Over partition statement as you suggested. Don't worry about it.